# Change a list of strings to lowercase

Tags: text-processing

I have two files, one file contains a list of strings.

```
+stringa +Dog +Cat
+cat +Tux +elephant
```

and the second file (csv) contains something like:

```
"123456 Abc","+Stringx +123","something"
"23456 dEf","+cat +Tux +elephant","Other something"
"34524 xyz","+stringa +Dog +Cat","third something"
```

the result should be:

```
"123456 Abc","+Stringx +123","something"
"23456 dEf","+cat +tux +elephant","Other something"
"34524 xyz","+stringa +dog +cat","third something"
```

How I can change the strings, that match my list of patterns, to lowercase?

My comma-separated values file have about 30 columns and about 1500 rows.

Comment: can you add some code you tried? what tools do you have? GNU sed? perl? awk?

Comment: Despite newer versions having an upper- & lower-case variable operator, bash is not a text editor.

Comment: @Sundeep I can not find the right approach. I do not understand `perl` but it is available. I use Debian 8.9 (Jessie). The point is i like change only the pattern, not the whole file. I have `sed`, `awk`, `tr`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `GNU sed`, assumes that you do not have any meta character in list of strings, `+` is not a meta character with default BRE

```bsh
$ # create substitute command for each line
$ sed 's/.*/s|"&"|\\L\&|gi/' f1
s|"+stringa +Dog +Cat"|\L&|gi
s|"+cat +Tux +elephant"|\L&|gi

$ # pass those commands as sed script
$ sed -f <(sed 's/.*/s|"&"|\\L\&|gi/' f1) ip.csv
"123456 Abc","+Stringx +123","something"
"23456 dEf","+cat +tux +elephant","Other something"
"34524 xyz","+stringa +dog +cat","third something"

$ # or save them in a file and use
$ sed 's/.*/s|"&"|\\L\&|gi/' f1 > f2
$ sed -f f2 ip.csv
```

- `\L` to convert string to lowercase
- `g` for replacing all occurrences in a line, `i` for case-insensitive matching

If you don't have `GNU sed`

```bsh
$ # \Q to quote metacharacters
$ # but will have issues if you have \ or $ or @
$ sed 's/.*/s|\\Q"&"|\\L$\&|gi;/' f1
s|\Q"+stringa +Dog +Cat"|\L$&|gi;
s|\Q"+cat +Tux +elephant"|\L$&|gi;

$ perl -p <(sed 's/.*/s|\\Q"&"|\\L$\&|gi;/' f1) ip.csv 
"123456 Abc","+Stringx +123","something"
"23456 dEf","+cat +tux +elephant","Other something"
"34524 xyz","+stringa +dog +cat","third something"
```

As noted by Stéphane Chazelas, this could lead to code injection vulnerabilities if contents of `f1` is not under control

Comment: It may be worth noting that those amount to command injection vulnerabilities if the content of  `f1` is not under your control.

Comment: good observation as always :) added a note

Answer (score 2):

**`AWK`** solution (for your current input):

Assuming that the 2nd field is of main interest and values in search file are double-quoted.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ $0="\042"$0"\042"; a[$0]; next }
     $2 in a{ $2=tolower($2) }1' patterns FS=',' OFS=',' file.csv
```

- `$0="\042"$0"\042"` - wrap a *pattern* line with double quotes while iterating through the lines of `patterns` file
- `a[$0]` - capturing a *pattern* line into array `a`
- `$2 in a{ $2=tolower($2) }` - if the 2nd field value from line of `file.csv` file is in the list of patterns(i.e. array `a`) - convert all characters in it to lowercase `$2=tolower($2)`

---

The output:

```
"123456 Abc","+Stringx +123","something"
"23456 dEf","+cat +tux +elephant","Other something"
"34524 xyz","+stringa +dog +cat","third something"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`, assuming you want each *word* in the first file to be turned to lowercase:

```
perl -pe '
 BEGIN {local $/ = undef; $regex = join "|", map qr{\Q$_\E}i, split " ", <>}
 s/$regex/\L$&/g' file1.words file2.csv
```

`local $/ = undef` makes the record separator for the BEGIN block undefined so that the one invocation of `<>` there, slurps the whole first file (`file1.words`) in. We split that on whitespace (`split " "` is special in `perl` in the same way as `awk -F " "` is in `awk`), and join the resulting words with `|` after having *regex-quoted* them and made them case insensitive.

So we have a huge regexp that is something like `(?i:word1)|(?i:word2)|...` which we apply on each line of the second file in the rest of the code.

If it's each string in each *line* of the first file, then that can be simplified to:

```
perl -pe '
 BEGIN {chomp (@strings = <STDIN>); $regex = join "|", map qr{\Q$_\E}i, @strings}
 s/$regex/\L$&/g' < file1.strings file2.csv
```

There, we open the first file on stdin instead of passing it as argument. `<STDIN>` returns a list of its lines from which we remove the delimiters with `chomp`, and join with `|` as above.

If you don't want it to be limited to ASCII characters, add the `-Mopen=locale` option.

Comment: @Sundeep. That was my initial interpretation, but now that you mention it, you're probably right the _lines_ of `file1` are probably to be the strings to be matched. See edit.